# Replace Highlighted Text From Word File

Tags: vba, templates, ms-word, blueprism

So, this sub should replace the highlighted text in an input document with another text given in an input collection (i'm in blue prism), but it does not do anything as the result is the same highlighted text.
I can't figure out what could be the problem, any ideas?

```
Sub Main()
            Dim d As Object = GetDocument(handle, documentName)
            Dim r As Object = d.Range
            Dim i As Integer
            Dim current_text As String = Nothing
            Dim new_text As String = Nothing

            r.Find.Highlight = True
            r.Find.Forward = True

            For repeat As Integer = 0 To fields.Columns.count() - 1
                For index As Integer = 0 To fields.Rows.count() - 1
                    current_text = fields.Rows(index).Item(0)
                    new_text = collection.Rows(index).Item(repeat)

                    Do While r.Find.Execute(current_text)
                        If r.HighlightColorIndex = currentHighlight Then
                            r.Text = new_text
                            r.HighlightColorIndex = CInt(newHighlight)
                            r.Bold = newBold
                        End If
                        i = r.End


    r.Start = i

                Loop

            Next
            Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you have `Sub Main()`?

Comment: @Jerry just an edit mistake

Comment: You don't show the definitions or assignments for `currentHighlight` and `newHighlight`. Are you sure these comparisons are accurate? If you leave out everything excelpt `r.Text = new_text` does it replace?

Comment: @CindyMeister Yes it does replace if i leave it out, it never enters in the Do While loop so the problem must be in the Do condition

Comment: In your question is not clear what you are trying to accomplish or how does Blue Prism come into it. You are showing VBA code but don't say how and where exactly you are using this in your Blue Prism process which is important to figure out a solution in that context. If you are just unsure about the VBA, please remove the Blue Prism tag.

Comment: Where are you defining `fields`? It's not evident from the sample code you've provided that you've even declared it.

Answer (score 0):

I have been resolved/did the same thing using Macro. You can use below code for that, and modify as required, as here, replaced the text/tags in word document.

```
Set myDoc = WordApp.Documents.Add(Template:=TemplateFilePath, NewTemplate:=False, DocumentType:=0)
With myDoc.Range.Find
                                    .text = [Text to be find]                                        
                                    .Replacement.text = [Replacement Text]                                        
                                    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
                                    .Replacement.Font.ColorIndex = wdRed
                                    .Forward = True
                                    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
                                    .Format = True
                                    .MatchCase = False
                                    .MatchWholeWord = False
                                    .MatchWildcards = False
                                    .MatchSoundsLike = False
                                    .MatchAllWordForms = False
                                    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
                            End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast the Collection stage contents to text using "Utility Strings>Get Collection as CSV". Then remove the comas and replace with spaces e.g.(in c#):

```
string correctString = collectionCSV.Replace(",", " ");  
amendedCSV = correctString;
```

This can output a text-type data item (i.e. contents of the collection in text-type spaced at the comas) that you can then reference with "MS Word VBO>Type Text" to write it into the Word document wherever you need to place them.  You may need to reference System.IO.dll and System.IO namespace on the initialise page of your object.